# Ubuntu Launcher Toggle

Tags: unity, launcher, services, openvpn

I am looking to create a 'toggle' to put in my Unity Launcher to either start or stop my OpenVPN setting.

Basically I am looking for an icon that could either

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

or

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop
```

(either by choosing one option or the other or by toggling when I click it).

I'm in the process of migrating to Linux after a decade's worth of Mac usage, please keep it simple because my brain might've rotted. I know this is possible because I saw it on a former colleague's machine.

Output from route when I am not connected through the VPN:

```
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
  192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Output when I am connected through the VPN

```
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default         10.8.0.101      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
  default         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
  10.8.0.1        10.8.0.101      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
  10.8.0.101      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
  <OpenVPNserver>.net 192.168.111.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
  128.0.0.0       10.8.0.101      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
  192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: can be done very well, even make the icon toggle, depending on the connection. only thing is that you need to identify if the vpn is on or off. if you run in a terminal the command `route`, is there a identifying difference between off or on?

Comment: Yes, it is... when I am without VPN, I get this:`qubex@sputnik:~/$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0` whereas when I am running the OpenVPN connection I get something very different.

Comment: This: `Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.101      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.101      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.101      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
<openVPNserver>.net 192.168.111.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.101      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0`

Comment: Sorry about the truly ghastly formatting but I'm having some problems with these reply posts.

Comment: ...it is okay, I think it is good enough. To make it something nice, I need to be at home, will look at it then if noone else does.

Comment: That's very kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a toggle script, a description how to set up, two desktop files and their corresponding icons. Although the answer is a bit extensive, it is straightforward to setup.

**How it works**

If you click on the icon in the launcher, the script looks up if the VPN connection is up or down. In either case, it switches to the other option and the icon in the launcher will be replaced accordingly. After 10 seconds, the script checks if connection was actually established. If not, it changes the icon back to the correct one. You can change this "time out" set in the headsection of the script (`wait = 10`). (do not touch the other definitions, unless you know what you do)

[image] [image]

**A few remarks:**

- First and most important of all: running a script that asks for administrator's permissions, from a local directory, is a potential security risk by definition. You will not check the code of your script everytime you run it, and if someone with malicious intentions would be able to change the code, anything could happen. I would suggest to run the script from a secure location if you have (or should have) any doubts on who is doing what on your computer.
- To make it more smooth qua interface, I used gksu in the commands you provided, instead of sudo. gksu is not installed by default, you will have to install it.
- The script looks into what the shell returns on the command "route". As an identifier, I used `<OpenVPNserver>`, since that was the simpelest and most obvious string to look for. If the setup would be used for other types of connections, it will not be sufficient.
- To replace the icons in the launcher, according to the state of the connection, the script reads the current launcher's content. If you use 13.10 or 14.04, it should be fine, but the outcome of the gsettings -"call" looks a bit different on older Ubuntu versions, and will not work properly.
- Before the scrip changes the launcher, a backup (script) of the current launcher is created as `/.restore_currentlauncher.sh`. Although in the years I used it, I never needed it, it is good to have.

**How to use:**

**The icons:**

Right-click on the icons below and save them as `toggle_officon.png` (the white one) and `toggle_onicon.png` (the green one).

[image]
[image]

**The script**:  Copy the (all) text below, paste it into an empty file and safe it as `toggle_vpn.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import getpass
import time

# time to wait, to check if connection was established (set correct icon)
wait = 10
# identifying difference on route command
running_id = "<OpenVPNserver>"
# location of the launcher restore script
backup_copy = "/home/"+getpass.getuser()+"/.restore_currentlauncher.sh"
# name of the desktop file if connection is down
mention_ifdown = 'application://VPN_off.desktop'
# name of the desktop file if connection is down
mention_ifup = 'application://VPN_on.desktop'


def check_ifrunning():
    # check if connection is up or down
    get_routeinfo = subprocess.Popen(["route"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = (get_routeinfo.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8"))
    if running_id in output:
        return "running"
    else:
        return "not_running"

def read_currentlauncher():
    # read the current launcher contents
    get_launcheritems = subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings",
        "get",
        "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher",
        "favorites"
        ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return eval((get_launcheritems.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")))

def set_current_launcher(current_launcher):
    # before editing the launcher, create restore script
    backup_data = read_currentlauncher()
    with open(backup_copy, "wt") as create_backup:
        create_backup.write(
            "#!/bin/sh\n\n"\
            "gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "+\
            '"'+str(backup_data)+'"'
            )
    # preparing subprocess command string
    current_launcher = str(current_launcher).replace(", ", ",")
    subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings",
        "set",
        "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher",
        "favorites",
        current_launcher,
        ]) 

def set_icon(change_mode):
    # defines the appropriate icon in the launcher
    state = check_ifrunning()
    if state == "running":
        if change_mode == "set_current":
            iconset = [mention_ifup, mention_ifdown]
        else:
            iconset = [mention_ifdown, mention_ifup]
    elif state == "not_running":
        if change_mode == "set_current":
            iconset = [mention_ifdown, mention_ifup]
        else:
            iconset = [mention_ifup, mention_ifdown]
    # set the defined icon
    current_launcher = read_currentlauncher()
    if iconset[0] in current_launcher:
        pass
    else:
        index = current_launcher.index(iconset[1])
        current_launcher.pop(index)
        set_current_launcher(current_launcher)
        time.sleep(1)
        current_launcher.insert(index, iconset[0])
        set_current_launcher(current_launcher)

def toggle_connection():
    set_icon("set_alter")
    runcheck = check_ifrunning()
    if runcheck == "not_running":
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "/etc/init.d/openvpn", "start"])
    else:
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "/etc/init.d/openvpn", "stop"])
    time.sleep(wait)
    set_icon("set_current")

toggle_connection()
```

**The Desktop files**

The VPN_off desktopfile: copy the text below, enter appropriate paths to both the icon and the script, save it as VPN_off.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VPN_off
Exec=python3 /path_to_script/toggle_vpn.py
Icon=/path_to_icon/toggle_officon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

The VPN_on desktopfile: copy the text below, enter appropriate paths to both the icon and the script, save it as VPN_on.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VPN_on
Exec=python3 /path_to_script/toggle_vpn.py
Icon=/path_to_icon/toggle_onicon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

If you did the actions above, drag either one of these desktop files on to the launcher (you might have to log out and in) and it should work! If you dragged the "wrong" desktop file on to the launcher, it will be corrected on first use.

In case you need more specific information on details, leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I entered the VPN server's IP address into the script and now it is working perfectly. Thanks putting so much effort into it, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about that because I am new. I've done it now because it's better late than never. Thanks again for your help.